How to rename file at SFTP, using PostAsJsonAsync in C# & ASP.NET MVC
I am using C# & ASP.NET MVC, which I am not so good at. I have function already built in the system to upload files through SFTP.
It is called UploadFileAsync and takes one parameter.
Here is the code:
public async Task<IResult<string>> UploadFileAsync(URLDetails urlDetails)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(Routes.UploadsEndpoints.UploadFiles, urlDetails);
    return await response.ToResult<string>();
}

I am trying to expand this C# function to include another parameter to rename the file that gets uploaded.
I built this function but does not work:
public async Task<IResult<string>> UploadFileAsync(URLDetails urlDetails, string fileName)
{
    // Modify urlDetails to include filename (if supported)
    urlDetails.FileName = fileName;
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(Routes.UploadsEndpoints.UploadFiles, urlDetails);
    return await response.ToResult<string>();
}

And by "does not work" I mean: it transfers the files with their original name and the name is not changed.
Is there a way I can fix that?

A HTTP POST request is something entirely different than using SFTP ...... and whether or not you can rename the file being uploaded to this POST endpoint depends entirely on whether or not that endpoint supports renaming in the upload process. It might - it might not - check the documentation!

I'm not aware of any PostAsJsonAsync method of HttpClient taking a URLDetails as argument. Which overload is that, and what is URLDetails? Please edit the question so that it provides a minimal, reproducible example.
